# Creating a complex Elastic Search search index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have the following database structure :

categories(name)

services(name, category_id, user_id)

sub_services(name, service_id, user_id)

class(price)

timings(from, to, quantity, day, sub_service_id, class_id)

constraints(type, sub_services_id, user_id)

bookings(sub_service_id, booked_for_date, timings_id, user_id)

---

Now the relationship among the following tables is :

**Categories** 1:N **Services**

**Services** 1:N **Sub-Services**

**Sub-Services** 1:N **Timings**

**Sub-Services** 1:N **Constraints**

**Timings** 1:N **Class**

---

I am using Rails 4 and I want to use Elastic Search for searching in this application.

I am not able to figure out that how will I index my data into ES and how will I give the user to search sub-services and hide those sub-services if they don't have any quantity available.

Comment: Parent/child functionality would be a good match for your use case. Have a look at this blog post: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: @BigRon no :) I couldn't solve it.

Comment: @JagjotSingh I've got a similar case I'm working on. In your case are you trying to return just `Sub-Services`, or could it be any of the above models?